# When does Optim functions does not affected by start values?

Tags: r, optimization

First of all, please note that my following code gives result in few seconds.

I have a simulated data. Then, I fit a method to get the initial value for the maximum likelihood. I choose these initial values to be in some cases overestimate of the true values. That is, the initial values at some densities are larger than the true values. Then, I fit MLE to estimate the parameters using these initial values using `optim` function. What was surprising me is that, the MLE returns a good estimates even for over initial values. My question is, `optim` function should take these initial values as a starting values, hence, if they are larger than the true values, `optim` function hence, cannot return the true values. That because, it start by larger number!

Here is the code:

```
library(VineCopula) #very nice package for multivariate complex dependencies.
#matrix_structure
Matrix <- c(5, 2, 3, 1, 4,
0, 2, 3, 4, 1,
0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
Matrix <- matrix(Matrix, 5, 5)
# define R-vine pair-copula family matrix
family <- c(0, 3, 3, 4, 4,
            0, 0, 3, 4, 5,
            0, 0, 0, 4, 6,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
family <- matrix(family, 5, 5)
# define R-vine pair-copula parameter matrix
par <- c(0, 0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 3.9,
         0, 0, 1.1, 1.6, 2.9,
         0, 0, 0, 1.9, 2.5,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 4.8,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
par <- matrix(par, 5, 5)
# define second R-vine pair-copula parameter matrix
par2 <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
# define RVineMatrix object
RVM <- RVineMatrix(Matrix = Matrix, family = family,
                   par = par, par2 = par2,
                   names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"))
set.seed(123)
simdata <- RVineSim(300, RVM)

seq <- RVineSeqEst(data,RVM)
seq$RVM$par ##here will give a good initial estimates.
```

However, I would like to test the effect of the initial values over the estimation of the MLE. So, I multiply it by scalar.

```
 seq_new <- 2*seq$RVM$par
```

Then fit MLE to the data using the new initial values (larger than the original one and the true values).

```
mle <- RVineMLE(data,RVM,start=seq_new)$par
> mle$RVM$par

       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[2,] 0.1612381 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[3,] 0.9260212 1.157538 0.000000 0.000000    0
[4,] 1.5380371 1.612497 1.866877 0.000000    0
[5,] 4.0816980 3.114378 2.574102 4.901621    0    

Where the true parameter is:

 RVM$par
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0
[2,]  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0    0
[3,]  0.9  1.1  0.0  0.0    0
[4,]  1.5  1.6  1.9  0.0    0
[5,]  3.9  2.9  2.5  4.8    0
```

How does that happen? Why `optim` function used in `RVineMLE` does not affected by the larger values of the initial values from the true values?

Comment: `Initial values` does not mean all subsequent solutions can only be larger. They can also be smaller. If the estimation problem has no local optima, then the `optim`-solution should indeed not depend on the initial values.

Comment: @coffeinjunky thank you so much for your comment. it really appreciated. all the used densities are non-linear and I am looking for global optima. As I understand from my reading, if we use `optim` function then the stating values will not affect the MLE. Is that similar to your comment?

Comment: Look at https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/local_vs_global.png If your densities have local optima, then the starting values matter. If your densities don't have local optima, then the starting values do not matter for the final result (potentially for the time it gets there, though). As a rule of thumb, it is always good to try a few different starting values to check that the results are the same.